# Repository manager that manages binary dll files (Embedded C/C++ project artifacts) and that integrates with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, nexus, artifactory

Is there any Repository manager that manages the binary dll files and also integrates well with the Jenkins?

Can Nexus be used to manage the dll files as these files are created as a part of Embedded C/C++ Projects and not sure if Nexus Artifact Manager supports/integrates well with such Projects as it mainly supports the Java projects? 
Is there a way to automatically manage the upload and download of such project artifacts from Nexus/other artifact managers without the use of POM file? 
Suggest in case there are other Artifact Managers that supports binary artifacts.

Answer (score 7):

The Nexus repository manager is java oriented, but can be used to store any files you want. Binaries of all types or even just text configuration files.
To automate the file upload process, you can use `maven` from command line:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.you -DartifactId=file -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=exe -Dfile=c:\out\file.exe -Durl=http://yourserver/nexus/content/repositories/releases -DrepositoryId=releases
```

Then, to get the file, you should be able to get it directly with the following URL:

```
wget http://yourserver/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/you/file/1.0/file-1.0.exe
```

This is a simple approach to using Nexus as a general artifact repository.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information on the Nexus part. But again I believe there is a dependency on the maven part and the above mvn command will create a pom file to work with. However, I will check with the commands that you have provided and will try to integrate the same in the automated way using Jenkins. To access the files that have been uploaded on to the Nexus needs to be downloaded via the wget command from the build step in Jenkins or is there any plugin available that needs to be integrated along with the Nexus Integration plugin in Jenkins?

Comment: For uploading, you don't need a pom file. The command runs as is. All parameters are on command line. As for Jenkins integration, look into https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Repository+Connector+Plugin

Comment: Thanks for the information on the Repository Connector plugin, I will try to check on this and if this works well then it would be helpful as Nexus us been used for some projects .

Answer (score 7):

[Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) can be used to store any type of binaries.
Starting with Artifactory 4.0, you can create [generic repositories](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-GenericRepositories) which allows uploading packages of any type. You will not need to upload any POM files and Artifactory will not need to calculate any metadata (for example Maven metadata).
To deploy files you can use the [REST API](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifact) or the [UI](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Deploying+Artifacts), for example:

```
curl -uUSER:PASS -T file.dll http://localhost:8081/artifactory/dll-local/path/to/file.dll
```

If you have a certain layout you would like to use for this repository you can create a [custom layout](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts) and associate it with the repository. This can be useful for automatic snapshot/integration versions cleanup and other module management tasks.

---

Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with Artifactory

Comment: Thanks for the information on the Artifactory tool . I would be more interested in the custom layout. I will have a look at this once.

Comment: Also, is there any dependency plugin that needs to be integrated with the Artifactory plugin to work with Jenkins?

Comment: @drsdarpan the Jenkins Artifactory has some optional dependencies on other plugins specified [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin)

Answer (score 2):

The open source version of Nexus (Nexus OSS) is supports many repository formats out of the box including Maven, NuGet, NPM, RubyGems and others. Nexus just runs on Java (e.g. like Jenkins). It is not Java only...

Depending on how you plan to get the DLL files from the repository, different formats might be more or less suited to your usage. You could even use a custom format, but then you rely custom tools.

The scenarios I have seen at many customers are

- using a Maven repo and pulling the files in either in a Maven build together with the Maven NAR Plugin (used for native development with C/C++)
- using a Maven repo and pulling via plan HTTP GET calls using your scripting language/build tool of choice
- using NuGet format and store the DLLs in NuGet packages in the repo and using nuget to retrieve them for the projects

All of these work well.

Comment: Many thanks for providing the different options on the plugins that can be integrated to upload and download the files.  I will surely have a look at these options once  as using Nexus would be the preffered options as Nexus is already been used for Java projects, so if Nexus can also support the binaries then that would be great.